# soundness and completeness on propositional logic?

Tags: logic

I was looking over on UCBerkley's intro to AI chapters slides on propositional logic and was confused by slide 9 http://faculty.ist.unomaha.edu/ylierler/teaching/ai_material/chapter07.pdf
on how they define soundness and completeness. it mentions that **soundness** means
$$ KB\vdash\alpha\implies KB \models\alpha$$
and **completeness**:
$$ KB \models\alpha \implies KB \vdash\alpha$$

can someone explain?

Comment: Explain what?${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundness of a logic means that provability implies satisfiability. Now $X \vdash \alpha$ means that $X$ proves $\alpha$ from the basic rules of deduction. If we let $w: PV \to \{0,1\}$ be a truth assignment, the satisfiability relation can be defined. We say that $X \models \alpha$ if for every $w \models X$, $w \models \alpha$ where $w \models X$ is taken to mean that $w \models \beta$ for all $\beta \in X$ and $w \models \beta$ is taken to mean that $w(\beta) = 1$. So soundness tells us that if we can deduce some formula $\alpha$ from a set of formulas $X$ and the basic rules of deduction, then the set of formulas $X$ must imply that the formula $\alpha$ is true. Now completeness tells us that the converse is also true. That is, if some set of formulas $X$ implies that a formula $\alpha$ is true, then we can prove the formula $\alpha$ from the set of formulas $X$ and the basic rules of deduction. Therefore, we have $X \vdash \alpha \iff X \models \alpha$.